# ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH login failing without static credentials

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have the following flow where I try to log in:

```
Map<String, String> authParams = new HashMap<>();
        authParams.put("USERNAME", email);
        authParams.put("PASSWORD", oldPassword);

        AWSCognitoIdentityProvider provider = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_1)
                .build();

        AdminInitiateAuthRequest adminInitiateAuthRequest = new AdminInitiateAuthRequest()
                .withClientId(APP_CLIENT_ID)
                .withUserPoolId(POOL_ID)
                .withAuthFlow(AuthFlowType.ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH).withAuthParameters(authParams);

        AdminInitiateAuthResult result = provider.adminInitiateAuth(adminInitiateAuthRequest);
```

But when I run this I get:

```
com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.InvalidParameterException: Missing required parameter auth parameters. (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: fddb5a6d-fb9f-4456-a8fa-faf75a2bd94e; Proxy: null)
```

The flow succeeds if I do (locally):

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
"accessKey",
"secretKey");

and do:
AWSCognitoIdentityProvider provider = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder.standard()
.withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
.withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_1)
.build();
```

Is there something that I need to enable to use ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH? As you can see I have it enabled. [image]

Comment: As per [aws-sdk-java](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-cognitoidp/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/cognitoidp/model/AdminInitiateAuthRequest.java#L1211-L1212 "aws-jdk-java") source code, for `ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH` flow `SECRET_HASH` is required if the app client is configured with client secret. But I'm not sure if this is your case.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was passing null inadvertently as the oldPassword. That made the API give the 'Missing Required Parameter'